# metarig moves my mesh in pose mode but rig won't

Tags: rigging, rigify

I used the rigify tool with automatic weights. I tested it in pose mode and the mesh was moving with the bones or with the rig but the automatic weights painted the mesh in weird ways. I then decided to correct the weight painting, bone by bone. I am not an expert but I tried to move each bone after to see if the mesh was attached and it was fine. I then decide to go into pose mode to use the rig (the one with the controls, not the metarig) and the mesh now does not move with the rig. If I select a bone and rotate it, the mesh moves with it, but if I select any of the rig controls and rotate it, the mesh does not follow. If I parent it again, I will lose my edited weight paints. What should I do with this?
Thanks for looking at this!